How to run Python files by clicking a link in another file?
New to Streamlit and Flask. I am trying to create a simple page containing links. When these links are clicked, I want the connected files to run in the new window or tab. Here is my code that is trying to achieve this. But the new link does not show anything. Also, the port keeps on changing.
main.py
import streamlit as st
import subprocess
from flask import Flask, Response
import threading

# Define a dictionary mapping filenames to Python scripts
scripts = {
    "Script 1": "script1.py",
    "Script 2": "script2.py",
    # Add more scripts as needed
}

# Route for running Script 1
app_script1 = Flask(__name__)

@app_script1.route("/run_script1")
def run_script1():
    # Use subprocess to run the Streamlit app for Script 1
    subprocess.Popen(["streamlit", "run", "script1.py"])
    return Response(status=204)

def start_flask_app_script1():
    app_script1.run(port=8503)


# Route for running Script 2
app_script2 = Flask(__name__)

@app_script2.route("/run_script2")
def run_script2():
    # Use subprocess to run the Streamlit app for Script 2
    subprocess.Popen(["streamlit", "run", "script2.py"])
    return Response(status=204)

def start_flask_app_script2():
    app_script2.run(port=8504)

# Start the Flask app for Script 2 in a separate thread
threading.Thread(target=start_flask_app_script2).start()

# Display links for running each script
for script_name in scripts:
    if st.button(script_name):
        if script_name == "Script 1":
            # Start the Flask app for Script 1 in a separate thread
            threading.Thread(target=start_flask_app_script1).start()
            script_url = "http://localhost:8503"
        elif script_name == "Script 2":
            threading.Thread(target=start_flask_app_script2).start()
            script_url = "http://localhost:8504"
        st.markdown(f'<a href="{script_url}" target="_blank">{script_name}</a>', unsafe_allow_html=True)

script1.py1
import streamlit as st
st.write("Inside script1.py")

script1.py1
import streamlit as st
st.write("Inside script2.py")


Looks like you haven't seen my answer. Kindly see

Link running python script directly is not recommended due to security issues. Instead the link if clicked leads to a url. For the same url, a function is run in the python file which inturn run another function where your scripting logic is present.
HTML in which the links to be clicked for running python scripts
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
    <a href="{{ url_for('run_script_1') }}">Run Script-1</a><br><br>

    <a href="{{ url_for('run_script_2') }}">Run Script-2</a><br><br>

    <a href="{{ url_for('run_script_3') }}">Run Script-3</a><br><br>   
</body>
</html>

Function containing logics from separate Python file in the same directory of main python file
scripts.py
def function_for_script_1():
    # Your logic here
    
def function_for_script_2():
    # Your logic here
    
def function_for_script_3():
    # Your logic here
    
    

MAIN PYTHON FILE
from flask import Flask as fl
from flask import render_template as tmp
from flask import url_for
from scripts import *

app = fl(__name__)    
@app.route('/run_script_1')
def run_script_1():
    result = function_for_script_1()
    return tmp('index.html', result=result)
    
@app.route('/run_script_2')
def run_script_1():
    result = function_for_script_2()
    return tmp('index.html', result=result)
    
    
@app.route('/run_script_3')
def run_script_3():
    result = function_for_script_3()
    return tmp('index.html', result=result)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
    
    
    

HTML in which script is run and the result is shown(index.html)
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

    <h1>{{ result }}</h1>

</body>
</html>


"Link running python script directly is not recommended due to security issues." Are you saying that what's being done in the question has security issues, or just that setting up the server to run arbitrary Python scripts from a URL has security issues?

What I meant by direct linking is say: If we mention  in html and in the function def function_for_script_1(): return render_template('index.html'), This will work even. But thiis is not advisable. Instead map this function thru another function run_script()

Why is that not advisable?

The browser doesn't have a secure way to directly execute Python code on the server. This could expose sensitive server-side logic or allow unauthorized code execution.I mean that the separaee python file executed wouldn't necessarily be visible in the console you use for development. But If the separate script encounters errors during execution, you might see those errors logged in the web server's error logs (not necessarily your development console). These logs are usually configured to capture issues that arise during web server operation
